# How to check Edittext value If User Enter existing Value Value cant be Add in List?

Tags: java, android

As you can see I am trying to add value in list but When I am Trying to add Existing Value In value is inserted

```
mylist = new ArrayList<>();

mylist.add(text);
Log.d("mylist",mylist.toString());

for (int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
   if(mylist.contains(mylist.get(i))) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ mylist.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.d("dataa",mylist.get(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting here. You've added an item to your list, then for each element *in the list*, you check whether than element is *in the list*, which is obviously true each time. What is this sample actually supposed to be doing?

Comment: I’m trying to add elements into the list but when I am add 1st time value in the list it’s show always item found in list but list is not have already values so please can you tell me how to check existing value in list and check if value exist values can’t be add in a list.

Comment: In the code you've provided, the list does have values as you've added to it immediately after initialisation. I think you're trying to determine whether something is already in the list before you add it, but that's not what your code is doing.

Comment: yes,So you can tell me how Its Work?

Comment: Like I said, you should check whether `text` is in the list before you add it.

Comment: okay,Thanks I Add value in List And Remove Duplicate Value from the list now i store ArrayList In Shared preference Value is store In shared pref But When I click On back Button Shared pref Value Will be Clear ?Why is like That??

Comment: That sounds like a different question than the one above, so feel free to ask a new question if you've exhausted all research. However there should be enough tutorials and already answered questions to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Condition `mylist.contains(mylist.get(i))`  is always `true`.

Comment: Yes it’s returned always true but my list not have duplicates value